# Align a div to the right of another and have it look the same regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck on this and I'd like to align a div to the right of another without messing with the width or height preferably. [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxV2X.png). I'd like the notation note right next to the equation. Here's what I tried (CSS code):

```
#rec-nb
{
   position: relative; 
}

#rec-ic
{
    position: absolute;
    right:400px;
    top:515px;
}
```

The issue is: This is fine on my PC screen, however on my MacBook, it's messed up and is on top of the equation. Any ideas?

EDIT: Fixed. It was an indent problem. Now it looks fine with the code I have.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want them to align and fit in height perfectly you need to use Flexbox on a container that contains both elements. If you wish to the notation box to stay in the same proportion and be visible at a specific position you should use float while the notation box must be a child element of the main element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was able to fix it. I realized I was inside another div that was not allowing me to adjust it properly. Indentation is difficult to see when there's a lot of div that was my fault. Thank you though!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

maybe use vw(viewport), cmiiw

```
example : margin-right: 20vw;
```

Comment: vw =/= viewport. It is viewport width. I fail to see how adding a margin on the right side would solve the alignment issue. That would just work on the relative parent element and space it away from the screen. It will have no effect on an absolute positioned. Overall it will not add anything that is intended here.